# Device::SerialPort not sending my data unless I cat the serial port

Tags: linux, perl, serial-port

Hi,
I am having an odd issue with my small script to interact with a serial port using `Device::SerialPort`.
My code is as follows:

```perl
use Device::SerialPort;
my $port = new Device::SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0") or croak("no.... $!");
$port->baudrate(9600) || die "failed setting baudrate: $!";
$port->parity("none") || die "failed setting parity: $!";
$port->databits(8)    || die "failed setting databits: $! ";
$port->stopbits(1) or die "failed setting stops: $!";
$port->handshake("none") || die "failed setting handshake: $!";
$port->write_settings or croak("Failed setting... everything: $!");
my $foo = $port->write("o0") or croak("Failed writing: $!");
die("WRITE FAILED!\n") unless $foo;
die("WRITE INCOMPLETE!\n") if $foo != 2;

$port->close() or die("close.... $!");
```

The odd thing is that if I do `cat /dev/ttyACM` before I run the perl code, it all works as expected.

I have tried adding `open($fh, '<', '/dev/ttyACM0');` to open the port like `cat` should do, but alas, no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: Ok.. something odd. If I set the serial port to 9600 with `stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 raw speed 9600` and trying to `echo o0 > /dev/ttyACM0` it doesnt work. But if I however do `cat /dev/ttyACM0`while doing the echo it works fine.

The device in the other end is an Arduino Mega, if that has something to do with this..

`cat > /dev/ttyACM0` works in every situation, but not exactly what I want as cat never exits.

Answer (score 0):

By "doesn't work," what do you mean?  Does the write hang, or does the data disappear?

I suspect you're running afoul of some flow control setting.  I'm not specifically familiar with the Arduino, but if it supports hardware flow control, then you might fiddle with those settings.

Comment: It doesnt hang, the data just disappears. I have to resend the data after opening `cat`. Ill look into the flow control and report back, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Adding `<` makes the file handle read, whereas you probably want it to be for write. You would therefore want to open it for write `>` or for append `>>`.
Furthermore, since the OS caches file buffers, you have to flush it. See [here in the perdoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-flush/unbuffer-an-output-filehandle?-Why-must-I-do-this?) on how to do it.

Comment: any particular reason that this was voted down? is it the wrong answer? if so, why?

Comment: It wasnt my -1, but perhaps someone -1 it because of < is read like `cat` does, and cat works. And >> is append, and that isnt what works.